# convert .srtm to xyz ord grd

Tags: mapping, gis

I need to plot bathymetry map of my study region and need to convert the .srtm to .xyz or .grd format to use GMT. I tried to do this with grdraster and xyz2grd, but got wrong results. I found that there is srtm2grd command in Linux but I do not have it in my commands. the data are in the following address: ftp://topex.ucsd.edu/pub/srtm30_plus/srtm30/data/

Comment: srtm comes as decimal lat/lon with height values above or below reference ellipsoid. Converting lat/lon to cartesian (e.g.wgs84) is straight forward. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates#1185413. Extrude height along ellipsoid surface normals, not centric normals.

Comment: suggest moving this to Geographic Information Systems stack ex change

Comment: I would use [`gdal_translate` of GDAL](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#gdal-translate) to convert the SRTM file into a format of your choice. GDAL has a driver for [SRTM files v1.0 and 3.0](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/srtmhgt.html). If I were in your situation, I would create a NetCDF file because I know how to handle them and GMT can read them. GDAL can even create a [GMT-compliant NetCDF file](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gmt.html). Not sure what that means ... . I don't have time in the moment to try it myself.

Comment: I wouldn't do the conversion by hand if there were trusted tools like GDAL. Converting  elevation data between different Earth shapes by hand might be easy from a purely technical/mathematical perspective. But, there might be introduced some errors if ones has no idea about different reference systems and Earth shapes ... .

Comment: @a_donda The `.xyz` format for GMT doesn't need cartesian coordinates as requested in [Converting from longitude\latitude to Cartesian coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates#1185413). The GMT xyz Format describes the elevation (`z`) above a reference ellipsoid at a specific location at the surface of the reference ellipsoid (`x,y`). `x` and `y` are expected to be longitude and latitde coordinates in degree East and degree West. Thus, `xyz` rather means `lon-lat-z`.

Comment: I see. I wrote a conversion routine for srtm data for my terrain renderer to convert them from geodetic to cartesian (it's just a few lines in C++) to render them in opengl. Wasn't aware that .xyz is a format, thought it was just meant as a paraphrase for cartesian. It takes longer to install GDAL (not mentioning learn the command syntax) than to write the method in an ellipsoid class. I wouldn't trust GDAL on srtm v4.1 data when there's a manual method :-)

Comment: @a_donda Thanks for the background. _"I wouldn't trust GDAL on srtm v4.1 data when there's a manual method :-) "_ => Than better by hand :-D

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:** *This is not the solution to the question in the title **but it solves the problem described in the question's text**.*

## Alternative solution

I would download the `netCDF` files from the `grd` directory instead of the `srtm` files from the `data` directory on the FTP server. The `netCDF` files can directly be plotted by GMT.

## Example

Based on this file: [e020n40.nc](ftp://topex.ucsd.edu/pub/srtm30_plus/srtm30/grd/e020n40.nc)

```
#!/bin/bash

outfile=pic.ps
infile=e020n40.nc
invar=z
colorfile=colors.cpt

gmt makecpt -Cviridis -D -T-5200/2400/400 > ${colorfile}

gmt psbasemap -R20/60/-10/40 -JM18 -B4/4"NSEW" -X+1.5c -P -K > ${outfile}
gmt grdimage ${infile}?${invar} -R -J -C${colorfile} -O -K >> ${outfile}
gmt pscoast -J -R -Di -W1,black -O >> ${outfile}
```

output (`pic.ps` imported into GIMP v2.8.22 in 60 dpi resolution and with strong antialiasing):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

QGIS does it easily.
open the NETCDF (or whatever format the SRTM sits in) by add raster
right click on the menu item and select export
choose the file format as .xyz

DONE!

Answer (score 0):

thanks everybody for your comments and reply
I used the  *grdconvert* command  in GMT to convert the mentioned .srtm to .grd format.

Comment: Please provide some example code on how the conversion works. This might help other users having the same problem. Thanks.